# Short story or Novella circa 1940, 1950

Tags: story-identification, mutant, evolution

Theme was man and woman (she was chosen specifically for his preferences) operating as guards or mentors as mankind was on the cusp of evolution, but did not recognize the marvels that awaited upon this "mutation".

Comment: This is a little broad... Where did you read the story, and in what language? What was the story's plot - who did the guards work for? What kind of mutation/evolution was taking place?

Comment: *Who* chose them? Gods, space aliens, time travellers from the future, an AI? What did the guards do, what were they guarding against?